# Kubernetes Configmap directory and subdirectory files

Tags: kubernetes

Having issue while creating configmap for directories and sub-directory and files. For example having folder structure as like below

```
.
├── build
│   └── book
│       └── book.txt
├── deploy
│   └── k8
│       └── deploy.txt
└── test
    └── tablet
        └── tab.txt

6 directories, 3 files
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testmap
  labels:
    conf: testmap
data:
```

I am really not sure how to implement to get config map for this, could you please some one help me on this.

Comment: What do you want in your ConfigMap? What do you want to achieve? You can also use multiple ConfigMaps.

Comment: Using configMap i want to mouth all the above folder and sub-folder as well

Comment: You can create an ConfigMap for each file and mount it at the patch you want.

Comment: Hi Jonas, see i have more than 10 folders and and sub-folder as well, in this case i have create many configmap for each file

Comment: Did you take a look: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62421 ?

Comment: I have completed this task, i will post the answer soon

Comment: Can you post your answer as you have found solution ?

Comment: Hi Malgorzata, answer is updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here the steps

```
1) select your directory and make it as a tar file (i.e tar -zcvf file.tar.gz /tmp/file)
2) kubectl create configmap test-configmap --from-file=file.tar.gz --dry-run -o yaml >test-configmap.yaml
3) create volume mounts

- mountPath: /tmp/file.tar.gz              
  subPath: file.tar.gz
  name: file

command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "tar -xf /tmp/file.tar.gz while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]

4) create volume as a config map

volumes:
- name: file
configMap: 
            
  name: file
  items:
            
  - key: file.tar.gz
    path: file.tar.gz
```